# Is there a way to provide a sort order to an mdfind query?

Tags: spotlight, command-line

In trying to get a list of all music files from a particular album using mdfind I see that the files aren't necessarily returned in any order.  I'd prefer album/track order if possible, but can't find a way to provide the sort order on the command line.  The current invocation is something like:

```
mdfind -onlyin "$MUSICROOT" -literal "$MDQUERY"
```

where:

```
$MUSICROOT is ~/Music/iTunes
$MDQUERY is "kMDItemContentTypeTree == 'public.audio' && kMDItemAlbum == '*$1*'c"
```

Ideally I'd want to add something like the following to the query:

```
ORDER BY kMDItemAlbum, kMDItemAudioTrackNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, 'sort'.

e.g. mdfind -onlyin "$MUSICROOT" -literal "$MDQUERY" | sort

will sort the output alphabetically, giving you Artist, Title, Track.
(it won't do the cool iTunes trick of ignoring 'The').

The sort command has lots of options, including sorting on particular fields if you want more control.

Edit:  The below shell script function will provide the desired sort in the specific case mentioned:

```
function sort_file()
{
    TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/sortable.XXXXXX` || exit 1
    export MDLS="mdls -raw -name kMDItemAlbum -name kMDItemAudioTrackNumber"
    export TR="tr \"\0\" \"\;\""
    awk '{system( "$MDLS \"" $0 "\" | $TR" ); print "\;"$0; }' $1 > $TMPFILE
    sort -t\; -k 2n -k 1f $TMPFILE | awk -F";" '{ print $3; }' > $1
}
```

Comment: The problem with piping the output to sort is that mdfind outputs filenames and I want to sort on metadata associated with the files.  sort was going to be my backup solution because it will require me to do an mdls for each result pipe that to a file, then sort the file on those fields and output the filename.

Comment: Sorry, I was going by the examples you gave and thought that their filename equivalents would be sufficient.

Comment: I played around with mdfind, mdls, awk and some other Unix tools last night but couldn't get it to work correctly and consistently (mainly because mdfind/mdls output isn't very Unix friendly in terms of parseability) :-(

Comment: I'm going to go with the sort solution because I don't think mdfind allows a sort.    If I used the spotlight API I could provide a sort callback but it would still generate the unsorted list of data first.

Comment: mdfind should be able to output null-separated filenames with `-0`, perhaps that could help with parsing.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following shell function to provide the sort:

```
function sort_file()
{
    TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/sortable.XXXXXX` || exit 1
    export MDLS="mdls -raw -name kMDItemAlbum -name kMDItemAudioTrackNumber"
    export TR="tr \"\0\" \"\;\""
    awk '{system( "$MDLS \"" $0 "\" | $TR" ); print "\;"$0; }' $1 > $TMPFILE
    sort -t\; -k 2n -k 1f $TMPFILE | awk -F";" '{ print $3; }' > $1
}
```

META NOTE: I would have put this in a comment in the above answer, but couldn't get it to format correctly.

Comment: I believe you can edit the previous answer to add this great script - it will get approved once someone else reviews it. Nice improvement - far too much for a comment!